# Multiple logistic regression: levels of categorical predictors that will never be combined – is that a problem?

Tags: logistic, categorical-data

I am investigating the predictors for adverse events (AEs) from a sample of 400 patients recieving an injection therapy. The outcome AEs is binary and I will use a multiple logistic regression model:

AEs = diagnosis + region + structure
(R code: `model=glm(AEs~Dia+Reg+Struc,family="binomial")`)

The levels of each of the variables are:

```
AEs: 1 or 0
Diagnosis: RA, OA, or other
Region: Shoulder, elbow, foot, hand, hip, knee
Structure: Joint, tendon, bursa
```

Then I came to think about:

1) Is it a problem, that some combinations are impossible/will not be present in the dataset? E.g. ’other’ will never be combined with ’hip’, ’elbow’ will never be combined with ’joint’ etc.

2) If not; I have considered adding interactions between all the predictors, because it clinically makes sense. However, will 1) be a problem for the model in that case (I am aware of that I will not get any estimate for e.g. ’elbox:joint’ etc., but does it harm the model?).
(R code: `model=glm(AEs~Dia+Reg+Struc+Dia*Reg*Struc,family="binomial")`)

Answer (score 1):

Your model should be fine. You will find when you fit the interaction (your point 2) that glm will warn you that it has had to drop a term from the model (I have forgotten the exact warning message) but it is a warning, not an error. The only thing to beware of is if for some combination either all patients had an AE or, more optimistically, none of them as then the coefficient for that combination will try to go to infinity, a problem know as separation (also known as Hauck-Donner effect).

Try it and see.